# Can i use my recovery disk in another same model laptop with same configuration?

Tags: system-restore

My question is: can I use my recovery disk in another same model laptop; a Dell XPS L502x.

I have 2 GB Nvidia graphics processor, the other one has a 1 GB Nvidia graphics processor. That is the only difference.

Everything else is the same. The operating system is Windows 7 Home Premium, 64 bit, 15 inch screen.

Comment: Legally, almost certainly no. If you bought your winders separately, then yes. Which recovery software? Is "my recovery" a new brand I haven't picked up on yet? Dell something? Why not ask them?

Answer (score 0):

Recovery disks, if made by a user, can have some modifications that are unique to that users computer.  Other than that they just contain info on setting a computer back to the defaults on that disk.  If the disk came from Dell and was not user made then it will just have factory defaults and all is good.

BUT!!!!  If the graphics cards have different drivers and there is not a backup driver besides nvidia, then you could run into trouble, such as having no display at all.  You will want to look into if these cards are identical and run off of a universal driver or if they are very specific.

I imagine that if the nvidia driver fails though you could download it from another source, boot windows in safemode so that it uses the windows graphics, and then replace the driver that way.

Comment: Nvidia drivers are in almost all cases universal, the driver for one card will work exactly the same on another card.

Comment: not universal, but per line, ie GeForce, Quadra, etc